# Why is my jquery animation going slow and laggy?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey i am using the textillate.js plug in for my portfolio and i was testing the animation and it is really slow and laggy. dont know if its my laptop or not. The animation is my heading class and also whenever i did the animation in a separate page with only the header only it worked smoothly. is it possible my pages load time is affecting the animation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-us">

    <head>

      <title>Carlos Elizondo</title>    
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">

      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "animate.css">

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">



    </head>

    <body>

<!------------------------------------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------------------------------>        
      <header>
          <div class="header-bg"></div>

          <div class="header-dark">

            <div class="wrapper">

                <div class = "heading tlt">Hi. My Name is</div>

              <div class = "box-name">Carlos Elizondo</div>

              <div class = "heading tlt">I'm a future web developer and current student </div>

              <ul>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="ion-social-facebook"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="ion-social-twitter"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="ion-social-linkedin"></a>
                </li>

              </ul>

            </div>

          </div>

          <nav class = "clearfix">

              <a href = "#contact-title" class = "nav-links last">Contact</a>

              <a href = "#portfolio" class = "nav-links">Portfolio</a>

              <a href = "#skills" class = "nav-links">Skills</a>

              <a href = "#about-me" class = "nav-links ">About Me</a>

          </nav>

        </header>


<!------------------------------------------------------------ABOUT ME-------------------------------------------------------------------->

        <div class = "about-container">

            <div id = "underline">

               <h1 class = "title" id = "about-me">About Me</h1>


            </div>

            <div class = "about-me-wrapper">

                <div class = "details selfie wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="2s"></div>

                <div class = "details wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="2s">

                    <p id = "sum"><br>Lorem Ipsum </p>

                </div>

                <div class = "details wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="2s">
                    <div id = "details-hobbies">
                        <div class = "square">
                            <div class = "square-cont">
                                <div class = "ion-code ion-cont">
                                    <p class = "under-img">Coding

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "square">
                            <div class = "square-cont">
                                <div class = "ion-ios-basketball ion-cont">
                                    <p class = "under-img">Basketball
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "square">
                            <div class = "square-cont">
                                <div class = "ion-ios-people ion-cont">
                                    <p class = "under-img">Family</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "square">
                            <div class = "square-cont">
                                <div class = "ion-university ion-cont">
                                    <p class = "under-img">School</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


<!---------------------------------------------------------------SKILLS------------------------------------------------------------------->

        <div class = "skills-container">

            <div id = "underline-second">

               <h1 class = "title second" id = "skills">Skills</h1>

            </div>

            <div class = "skills-wrapper wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="3s">

                <div class = "skills">

                    <div class = "logo">

                        <div class = "ion-social-html5">
                          <p class = "des">HTML5</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>    

                </div>

                <div class = "skills">

                    <div class = "logo">

                        <div class = "ion-social-css3">

                          <p class = "des">CSS3</p>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class = "skills">

                    <div class = "logo">

                        <div class = "ion-social-javascript">
                          <p class = "des">JAVASCRIPT</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class = "skills last">

                    <div class = "logo">

                        <div class = "ion-social-angular">
                            <p class = "des">ANGULAR JS</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


<!--------------------------------------------------------------PORTFOLIO----------------------------------------------------------------->

         <div class = "portfolio-container">

                <div id = "underline-last">

                   <h1 class = "title last" id = "portfolio">Portfolio</h1>

                </div>

                    <div class = "portfolio-wrapper">

                        <a href = "#" class = "tiles wow slideInUp" data-wow-offset="280">

                            <div class = "port"><img src = "bg.PNG">
                                <div class = "content-overlay"></div>
                                 <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h3 class="content-title">Project #1</h3>
                                    <p class="content-text">Dallas Mavericks</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </a>

                        <a href = "#" class = "tiles wow slideInUp" data-wow-offset = "280">

                             <div class = "port"><img src = "bg2.PNG">
                                <div class = "content-overlay"></div>
                                 <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h3 class="content-title">Project #2</h3>
                                    <p class="content-text">ATLAS</p>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </a>


                        <a href = "#" class = "tiles wow slideInUp" data-wow-offset = "280">

                            <div class = "port"><img src = "bg3.PNG">
                                <div class = "content-overlay"></div>
                                    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                        <h3 class="content-title">Project #2</h3>
                                        <p class="content-text">ATLAS</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                        <a href = "#" class = "tiles wow slideInUp" data-wow-offset = "280">

                            <div class = "port"><img src = "bg3.PNG">
                                <div class = "content-overlay"></div>
                                 <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h3 class="content-title">Project #2</h3>
                                    <p class="content-text">ATLAS</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </a>

                        <a href = "#" class = "tiles wow slideInUp" data-wow-offset = "280">

                            <div class = "port"><img src = "bg3.PNG">
                                <div class = "content-overlay"></div>
                                 <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h3 class="content-title">Project #2</h3>
                                    <p class="content-text">ATLAS</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </a>

                        <a href = "#" class = "tiles wow slideInUp" data-wow-offset = "280">

                            <div class = "port"><img src = "bg3.PNG">
                                <div class = "content-overlay"></div>
                                 <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                                    <h3 class="content-title">Project #2</h3>
                                    <p class="content-text">ATLAS</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </a>

                    </div>

            </div>


<!-------------------------------------------------------------CONTACT-------------------------------------------------------------------->

        <div id = "contact-container">

             <div id = "contact-underline">

                <h1 id = "contact-title">Hey Lets Keep In Touch!</h1>

             </div>

             <div class="login-page">

                  <div class="form">

                    <form class="register-form">

                      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>

                      <input type="text" placeholder="email"/>

                      <input type="text" placeholder="subject"/>

                      <textarea placeholder="messge" rows = "7" cols = "60"></textarea>

                      <button>create</button>     

                    </form>

                  </div>
            </div>

        </div>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
      <script src = "jquery.lettering.js"></script>
      <script src = "jquery.textillate.js"></script>
      <script src= "wow.min.js"></script>
      <script>new WOW().init();</script>
    <!--<script src="viewportchecker.js"></script>-->
    </body>
</html>


<!----------------------CSS-------------------------------------------->

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------HEADER-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

header{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;


}

.header-bg{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(macbook2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;

}

.header-dark{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.wrapper{

    width: 850px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -50px;


}


h2{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;

}

h4{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

ul{   

    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;

}

ul li{

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 13px;


}


.ion-social-facebook{
   color: white;
   font-size: 28px;

}

.ion-social-facebook:visited{
    color: white;
}

.ion-social-facebook:visited{
    color: white;
}

.ion-social-twitter{

    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.ion-social-linkedin{
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
}


nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}

.nav-links{
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links.last{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

nav > a{
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav > a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;   

}

nav a:hover:before{
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.logo:link{

    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;

}

.heading{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.box-name{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px solid white;
    padding: 9px;
    font-size: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}



/*-----------------------------------------------------------ABOUT ME--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.about-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #ededed;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#underline{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0A0A0A;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.title{

   color: #0A0A0A;
   text-align: center;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   padding-top: 40px;
   font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
   font-size: 55px;


}

.about-me-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;                
    flex-direction: row;            
    flex-wrap: nowrap;              
    justify-content: space-between;
}



.details{
    position: relative;
    width: 370px;
    height: 470px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

.details.selfie{
    background-image: url(selfie2.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius: 10px;


}


#details-hobbies{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.square{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%; 
}

.square-cont{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.ion-cont{
    position: absolute;
    color: #0A0A0A;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 105px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.under-img{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #0A0A0A;
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;

}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------SKILLS--------------------------------------------------------------*/

.skills-container{

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;

}

.title.second{
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   padding-top: 40px;
   font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
   font-size: 55px;

}

#underline-second{

    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

}

.skills-wrapper{

    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;                
    flex-direction: row;            
    flex-wrap: nowrap;              
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.skills{

    width: 280px;
    height: 470px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-right: 4px solid black;
}

.skills.last{
    border: none;
}


.logo{
    width: 265px;
    height: 340px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.ion-social-html5{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 280px
}

.des{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: black;
}

.ion-social-css3{

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 280px
}

.ion-social-javascript{

     text-align: center;
    font-size: 280px
}

.ion-social-angular{

     text-align: center;
    font-size: 280px
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------PORTFOLIO---------------------------------------------------------*/


.portfolio-container{

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 870px;
    background-color: #444444;
    top: 0; 
    padding: 0;

}

#underline-last{

    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #f5f5f5;
    margin-bottom: 40px;


}

.title.last{

    color:#f5f5f5;

}

.portfolio-wrapper{

    position: relative;
    max-width: 990px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.port{
    position: relative;
    width: 280px;
    height: 315px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.port:hover{

    outline: #4169E1 solid 3px;
}


img{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.content-overlay{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.port:hover .content-overlay{
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.port:hover .content-details{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-details p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.fadeIn-bottom{
  top: 80%;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------CONTACT ME---------------------------------------------------------------*/

#contact-container{

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background: rgba(32,157,229,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(32,157,229,1) 0%, rgba(32,108,229,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(32,157,229,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(32,108,229,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(32,157,229,1) 0%, rgba(32,108,229,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(32,157,229,1) 0%, rgba(32,108,229,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(32,157,229,1) 0%, rgba(32,108,229,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(32,157,229,1) 0%, rgba(32,108,229,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#209de5', endColorstr='#206ce5', GradientType=1 );


}

#contact-underline{

    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #e1e1e1;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;

}


#contact-title{

    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.login-page{

    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 400px;
}

.form{
    position: relative;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    /*margin: 0 auto 80px;*/
    padding: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);

}

.form input{

   font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
   outline: 0;
   background: #f2f2f2;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0;
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   padding: 15px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 14px; 
}

.form textarea{

    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
   outline: 0;
   background: #f2f2f2;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0;
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   padding: 15px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 14px; 

}

.form button {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #1148a0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}


<!-------------------------------------JS--------------------------------->


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.heading').textillate({
        in: {
            effect: 'fadeInDown',
            delay: 1000,
            sync: true

        }
    });
});





$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It could be your CSS transition for same class or element

Comment: i don not have a transition for the heading class. am i suppose to add a transition is that what your are saying?